# Grafana SigV4 Authentication - Docker image?

Tags: image, docker, authentication, grafana, sigv4

we have a problem setting up aws-sigv4 and connecting an AWS AMP workspace via docker images.

> TAG: grafana/grafana:7.4.5

Main problem is that in the UI the sigv4 configuration screen does not appear.
Installing `grafana:7.4.5` locally via Standalone Linux Binaries works.

Just setting the environment variables,

> export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=true
> export GF_AUTH_SIGV4_AUTH_ENABLED=true

the configuration screen appears.

Connecting and querying data to AMP via corresponding IAM instance role is working flawlessly.
Doing the same in the docker image as ENV Variables does NOT work.

When using `grafana/grafana:sigv4-web-identity` it works, but it seems to me that this is just a "test image".
How to configure the default grafana image in order to enable sigV4 authentication?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
$ docker run -d \
  -p 3000:3000 \
  --name=grafana \
  -e "GF_AUTH_SIGV4_AUTH_ENABLED=true" \
  -e "AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=true"  \
  grafana/grafana:7.4.5
```

You didn't provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it's hard to say what is a problem in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use variable GF_AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG instead of AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).